# Right Panel Show/Hide while moving page content to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a right side panel that can expand and collapse. When the user clicks on the expand option, the contents of the body drops below instead of sliding to the left along with the panel.

How can i get the original content to slide to the left as well?

```
#panel
{
 height: 500px;
 width: 200px;
 background: black;
 float: right;
 display: none;    
 color: white;
 font-size: xx-large;
}
 #click
{
 height: 70px;
 width: 25px;
 background: #CB5152;
 float: right; 
 margin-top: 200px;
 }


<div id='panel'>
Info
</div>

<div id='click'>
<div id="inner" class="fa fa-calculator fa-lg"></div>
</div>

<script>
$('#click').click(function()
 {
$("#panel").animate({width:'toggle'},500);       
  });
</script>
```

FORM

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="site-index">
     <div class="body-content">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
             <form id="wizard_example" action="">
```

[BEFORE http://searcherrorcodes.com/stack/before.PNG](http://searcherrorcodes.com/stack/before.PNG)

[AFTER http://searcherrorcodes.com/stack/after.PNG](http://searcherrorcodes.com/stack/after.PNG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form (or it's container) is taking up 100% of the width (col-md-12), then there is no space to move the form left when the side panel is displayed. You would need to make the form smaller and center it on the page. You can also set the side panel to "position: absolute" (make sure the z-index is higher than any set for the form.) However, this would have the side panel display on top of the form.